# Simplistic photography location scouting app for iPhone

Tags: photography, iphone-app

I travel a lot as a photographer and from time to time I discover locations or just a single motives that I potentially want to revisit with my photography equipment.

So I would like to take some pictures with my iPhone, give the photos some description and maybe some tags. Then later at any time I want to be able to find out if I have any saved photos near me on a map.

So I am looking for a location scouting app for the iPhone that does the following:

- take a picture or import one from the camera roll
- give that single picture some tags and maybe a description
- show all pictures I took on a map
- search and filters those images on the map by description and/or tags
- show my current location on that map
- store those images independently from the iOS photos app
- sync those images with some sort of cloud service

As simple as that!

I know about [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24627/iphone-location-scouting-app-that-reads-geo-location-exif-data) and about [MapAPic Location Scout](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id519612179?pt=1020283&ct=so&mt=8) but that app is way too complicated to use with way to many features and also doesn't allow me to see the pictures on a map. I can only see defined locations without the pictures. What is worse, the pictures of a location don't even have to be taken at that location they could chave been taken on a totally different continent.

I also know I can see the pictures of my camera roll on a map directly in the photos app. This is exactly how I want it. **But**: It will show *all* pictures of my camera roll on the map and I have to keep the images in the camera roll. It would be much better if the "location images" are in a completely different "database" than my regular pictures.